# CCLabelTTF not working in iOS 6.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, cclabelttf

I am using cocos2d v0.99.5 and iOS deployment target is 5.0

when i run my app with Xcode 5.0 in iOS-7.0/5.0 simulator it is working fine. and  i run with Xcode 5.0 in iOS-6.1/6.0 simulator not working. i checked with breakpoint, it is crashing at the below code:

```
CCLabelTTF *mainGameTitle = [[CCLabelTTF alloc] initWithString:@"REGULAR PACK" dimensions:CGSizeMake(40, 50) alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft fontName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" fontSize:20];
```

and it shows like this:

[image]

When i write:

```
CCLOG(@"font names ====> %@",[UIFont familyNames]);
```

In this line also "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error occur in iOS-6.0 and 6.1.

I tried with CCMenuItemFont, this one also shows the above crash.

it is Working in 7.0 and 5.0 simulator/device. 
What is this issue? please help me?

Edit:

I tried with another method i.e

```
 CCLabelTTF *mainGameTitle = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"REGULAR PACK" fontName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" fontSize:20];
```

again i got same above UIFont issue in labelWithString:fontName:fontSize method.

Comment: please check some methode of CCLabelTTF is Deprecated...

Answer (score 2):

you use the CCLabelTTF method that is already Deprecated.see below screen shot

[image]

Comment: ok fine,but there are too much method of CCLabelTTF.Why you don't try.don't use any where deprecated method in your project.and deprecated is working at that time but in future it may be stop.

Comment: Finally i got the solution. I deleted some fonts in "Fonts provided by application" in Info.plist. It is working fine in all devices.

Answer (score 2):

Deprecated method states that below the particular version this won't work, not specifically in this method but in several method it is supportive and not supportive due to change in operating system and the functional flow of data.

You could try below method which would work on both platform

```
CCLabelTTF *label1 = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Hello World 1" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:50];
```

Thanks